# Get the filepath of a static file to work local and on server

Tags: c#

I want to provide a new file needed for configuring my application - here it's the `settings.json`: [image]

How do I get the correct path of the file?

I tried:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location // gets a DLL somewhere /Temporary ASP.NET Files/
```

but when I publish it to a customers server the location is next to the web.config like this (and is a different path):

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to get base directory of your application.

Something like this should work:

```
string settingsJson = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "settings.json");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these two methods:

```
string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory; 
Path.Combine(path, "settings.json");
```